# InstallShield: How to alleviate "Another version of this product is already installed..." error

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

First off, this differs from the question [handle "Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234879/handle-another-version-of-this-product-is-already-installed-installation-of-th) because this is not a development error- my users are seeing this error as well when they try to modify the installation.

Here's the problem: I can install my latest version of the application and everything works fine.  However, if I run the same installer again, rather than giving me the maintenance options (Repair/Modify/Remove) I get the above error, the full text of which reads:

> Another version of this product is already installed.  Installation of
> this version cannot continue.  To configure or remove the existing
> version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.

I can run the uninstall from the Add or Remove programs without incident, but I don't want my users getting this message if they need to fix the installation.  I have some custom scripts but otherwise my install sequence is unmodified.  When I try to run the verbose logging command, it launches the installer and the error occurs, but no log file is created.  That command is foo.exe /verbose".\LogFile.log"

Bumping the revision changes nothing.  It will upgrade the first time it's run, but then it displays the same error.  I'm using InstallShield 2021 R2.

Comment: in the "Application" event log you will have some informations that can help you to debug

Comment: Check %temp% folder. There should be some msi log with random numbers.